# Theorem 11.10 Rudin Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Following is from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.
[image]

In the last step it supposes $\mu^*(A_n) < \infty$ for all $A_n \in M_F(\mu) $. But when introducing $M_F(\mu) $ or $\sigma$-ring it did *not* suppose such condition . Is it necessary to include  hypothesis  $\mu^*(A_n) < \infty$ or the theorem still holds for $\mu^*(A_n) = \infty$ and if so how  to prove that case (I tried but couldn't make any progress) .

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the definition of "elementary set"?

Comment: @Randall please read the proof. $A-n$ are not all necessarily elementary sets

Comment: Yes, but aren’t they limits of such by definition?

Answer (score 1):

In definition 11.7 Rudin defines $\mu$ to be finite on elementary sets. Fix $A \in \mathfrak{M}_F(\mu)$. By definition this means that there exists elementary sets $A_n$ such that $d(A_n, A) \to 0$, where $d(A, B) := \mu^*((A-B) \cup (B-A))$.
Thus by subadditivity and by monotonicity one has
$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A_n \cup (A-A_n)) \leq \mu^*(A_n) + \mu^*(A-A_n) \leq \mu^*(A_n) + d(A, A_n).$$
Since $d(A_n, A) \to 0$, we may choose $n$ large enough that $d(A_n, A)< \infty$. Then since $\mu^*(A_n)$ is assumed to by finite since $\mu$ is assumed to be finite on elementary sets, we have both terms on the right hand side are finite, and hence $\mu^*(A) < \infty$. Thus any $A \in \mathfrak{M}_F(\mu)$ has $\mu^*(A) < \infty$.

Rudin is known for leaving out these little details.